# Translation for [まどろみの中で]

Tags: translation

Google translate keeps saying that it means 'in the middle of a snowfall'. Is the sentence a proverb or a figure of speech? Well...in short, I am confused.

Many Thanks

Comment: Zero bearing on anything but immediately RADWIMPS came to mind. Context might play a role in determining which of the two meanings for まどろみ is accurate. Is this from スパークル？

Answer (score 2):

微睡み（まどろみ）means a nap or a small rest, when you get slightly drowsy. You also have a second meaning which is pretty much the opposite : a sound sleep.

Here is the source for もどろむ, the verb it is derived from : https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%AE%E7%9D%A1%E3%82%80 (btw this dictionary is really a great online resource. You should probably bookmark it)

Comment: I know that 'まどろみ' means nap. My first thought is that the sentence means 'in the middle of a nap', which makes more sense to me. I'm just curious why google translates it as 'In the middle of a snowfall', even though there is no part for 'snow' in it. But thanks for the link, weblio looks really interesting. I''ll check it out.^^

Comment: That's not much of a mystery... Google translate is still pretty awful, especially when you give it strings of kana with fewer kanji.

Comment: oh no...didn't think they are THAT bad though....until now. They gave me good translation many times or good enough so I can figure it out myself. Well, at least my question is answered.^^

Comment: The problem with Google Translate comes from the fact that, when you enter a single word, Translate will provide you with the most used word for translation in its corpus of text or a basic translation a user provided. Also, the result is often unnatural (especially for Japanese since Translate don't take into account the fact that a Japanese conversation needs sometimes a context to be translated/interpreted)

Comment: I've found cases where Google Translate provides "translations" with opposite valence ("yes" becomes "no", etc.) depending on how many newlines were included at the *end* of the segment -- i.e., where they shouldn't have any bearing at all on the meaning.  Truly, _caveat lector_.